# Why does my UIActionSheet crashes when any button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a problem with my `UIActionSheet`. When I click on any button it crashes. I activated `NSZombieEnabled`. Then, I get the following error message.

```
[FacebookConfigurationController actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to
deallocated instance 0x84d4430
```

I put a breakpoint in my method

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index
```

But crashes before it stops. Here is my code, if you can help me

`FacebookConfigurationController.h`

```
@interface FacebookConfigurationController: UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate,...>
```

`FacebookConfigurationController.m`

```
-(void) LaunchFacebookMenu
{    
     if([Commentaire isEqual:@""])
    {
        NSLog(@"You must enter a comment");
    }
    else
    {
        UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: [self getLanguageValue: @"facebook_popup_title"]
                                                            delegate: self 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle: nil 
                                              destructiveButtonTitle: 
                                 [self getLanguageValue: @"facebook_popup_cancel"]
                                                   otherButtonTitles: 
                                 [self getLanguageValue: @"facebook_popup_userwall"], 
                                 [self getLanguageValue: @"facebook_popup_friendwall"],
                                 [self getLanguageValue: @"facebook_popup_deconect"],nil];
        action.actionSheetStyle =UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

        [action showInView:m_CurrentView.view];
        [action release];
    }
}




- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)Index
{ 
    switch (Index) 
    {

        case 0:
        {
            [m_CurrentView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {

         ...
         ...
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you release your `FacebookConfigurationController object`?

Because the delegate method

```
(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)Index{}
```

is called soon when you have release `"self"`.